# legend in scatter plot using dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, legend, scatter-plot

Only the first data name i.e 'Manchester City' is displayed in the legend.

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df1=pd.read_csv(r'F:\anoch\IPproject\FSTS\teams.csv')
df1.plot(kind='scatter',x='GOALS/90min', y='xG',c=['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow','black','purple','aquamarine','grey','tan','khaki'])
plt.legend(['Manchester City','Bayern Muchen','Real Madrid','Internazionale','Liverpool','Arsenal','FC Barcelona','Atletico Madrid','PSG','RB Leipzig'],bbox_to_anchor=(-0.1, 0.75))
plt.show()
```

[image]

I'm not an expert. I'm doing this for a school project. Any help from you guys would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is easier if you just go with matplotlib rather than pandas, as it gives you more control, also using legend() that way does not ensure it gets the correct color/team name:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Sample data as I do not have your csv
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "GOALS/90min": [1, 2, 3],
    "xG": [1, 2, 3],
    "team": ['Manchester City', 'Bayern Muchen', 'Real Madrid']
})

# this or add a column with df["colors"] = [...] or use some other method
colors = {'Manchester City': 'red', 
          'Bayern Muchen': 'green', 
          'Real Madrid': 'blue'}


for team in df1.team.unique():
    data = df1.loc[df1.team==team]
    plt.scatter(data['GOALS/90min'], data['xG'], color=colors[team], label=team)

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]